# Writing a function that returns 16-bit expression

Tags: c

The question following is excerpted from exercise 6, chapter 7, A book on C.

6. Write a function that will extract every other bit position from a 32-bit expression. The result should be returned as a 16-bit expression. Your function should work on machines having either 2- or 4-byte words.

Now there are two key points I do not understand about this question:

- What does it mean, "extract every other bit position"? I really do not understand this. For example, a 32-bit expression: 00000001 00000000 00000000 10011110, what can "extract every other bit position" do?
- The question seems to contradict itself: "Extract every other bit position from a 32-bit expression," then "your function should work on machines having either 2- or 4-byte words," but 2-byte words are only 16-bit expression; how can I extract every other bit position from an expression that is "both" 32-bit and 16-bit?

This question really makes no senses. One of  the things I really hate about this book is, compared to C prorgamming written by Kochan, which I have no problems at all in understanding its questions, so dense to understand with respect to exercise questions. Or may be I am just stupid!

Comment: 2-byte word on a specific machine doesn't mean that the machine supports only 16-bit expressions

Comment: The text means that you must use either `uint32_t` or `unsigned long` for the source so that it will consistently have 32 bits, and all arithmetic would happen at least with this type. For example `1 << i` would be wrong because that would be of type `int`; you need to do `1UL << i`.

Comment: You have it sorted out -- mostly. Extract every other bit position (means just what it says - extract bits `0,2,4,6...`. Working on any machine with 2-byte or 4-byte word is somewhat a *red-herring*. As long as you are using bit-shifts to extact, then word-size is irrelevant. You could even use a simple `for` loop, stepping 2, e.g. `unsigned someval = 0xdeadbeef; unsigned short n = 0; for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 32; i += 2, j++) n = n | (((someval >> i) & 1) << j);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin your instruction has been very helpful and you are very enthusiastic :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala on my machine, sizeof(int) == 4 bytes, so no worries :)

Comment: @SONTO then you didn't get the meaning of the assignment at all.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin and neither did you ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - yes, yes, exact width-types are called for, but in the comments I thought we would get the extraction taken care of before making his eyes roll back in his head by introducing the `uint32_t` type at the same time. But yes, to eliminate potential word-size differences for hardware where both `int` and `short` are 2-bytes [C11 Standard -- .2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"every other bit" means each either bits 0, 2, 4, 6 ... or bits 1, 3, 5, 7 ...

If you start with 32 bits and take each other bit then your result is 16 bits.